# If page is not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                do something

            }
```

But what if I need to do something if page is NOT postback?
Do I use else or there is other/better way??

Comment: I think you're confusing things. You _can_ do something on postbacks, but you should not databind your datacontrols on every postback in general. Also you seem to overlook the `logical negation operator (!)`(C#), so "do something" is only done `If Not Page.IsPostBack`(VB.NET).

Comment: You're already doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can "add return;"

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    do something
                    return;
                }
//it means else
```

Answer (score 13):

The most obvious solution would probably look something like this:

```
if (IsPostBack) {
    // It is a postback
} else {
    // It is not a postback
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `else` is the solution to your problem here.

```
if (!IsPostBack)             
{

} else {
{
   // Is a post back
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If page is not post back, you(server-side) don't want to do anything...
(For this user)-> Server have to wait until new command comes from client-side(user).

If you want to do a thing() that is not accourding with user-request, 
you can do it with a server-service etc.
( An ex.; Server service: server side folder(image resizer) <-> there is no need to postback )

Sorry for my english, but you get the idea, Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

**There are several different solutions:**

---

Using two separate `if` statements:

```
if (IsPostBack){
    // is a post back
}

if (!IsPostBack){
    // is not a post back
}
```

---

Using either of the following `if` `else` statements:

```
if (IsPostBack){
    // is a post back
} else {
    // is not a post back
}
```

OR

```
if (!IsPostBack){
    // is not a post back
} else {
    // is a post back
}
```

---

Using either of the following `return` statements:

```
if (IsPostBack){
    // is a post back
    return;
}
// is not a post back
```

OR

```
if (!IsPostBack){
    // is not a post back
    return;
}
// is a post back
```