# How do I mainain the state of checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a list of checkboxes in gridview.

You may check one or you may check as many as you wish, up to 10.

Once you check a box or boxes in a paging app, you page to the next page, the boxes are unchecked.

How do I keep the checked boxes to remain checked until a user unchecks them?

The code I have below isn't working.

```
For Each r As GridViewRow In GridMaks.Rows
    If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("makos"), CheckBox).Checked Then
        Dim marko As String = baseHint & "&cup=" & r.Cells(4).Text
        CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("marko"), CheckBox).Checked = True '// added this hoping to keep checkbox checked but it doesn't work
    End If
Next
```

Sorry for including 2 flavors c# and vb.net. I can convert c# to vb if it helps.

Comment: Where/when do you bind data to the gridview? Can you supply that code? If you're binding data each time the page loads, you probably want to add in a check to prevent binding from occurring on [Postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836697/if-page-is-not-postback).

Comment: @Sam, I bind data on page_load() event and also on page refresh:

refresh_click() event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're binding data to the grid each time a page loads, the checkboxes won't persist because they're being reset. Try performing a check like the simple sample code below to only bind data when the request is **not** a postback.

```
if (IsPostBack) { 
    // It is a postback, don't bind data
} else { 
    // It is not a postback, bind data
}
```

Also, you may find this article regarding [Persisting checkbox state while paging](http://www.highoncoding.com/Videos/697_Persisting_CheckBox_State_While_Paging_in_GridView_Control.aspx) helpful for what you need. In the GridView's "PageChanging" event, the article says to store the row index of each row that has a **checked** checkbox in a List, then store that List within the ViewState. When the page changes, retrieve that List from the ViewState and repopulate the GridView checkboxes.